# Is there a benchmarking/monitoring tool that can be targetted towards running applications?

Tags: software-recommendation, application-development, monitoring, tools, benchmarks

I am trying to fix a performance issue bug on one of the core apps, and I would like to know if there is any benchmarking or monitoring tool that I can use to compare my different branches use of CPU.

Thanks.

Comment: `sudo intel_upload_blit_large` can be used for microbenchmark of Intel GPU performance

Comment: @Pandya Neat thanks; will this do it on just a system wide level, or can it tell me about specific applications using it?

Comment: Also search for **`sysbench`** - A modular, cross-platform and multi-threaded benchmark tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you talked about "core apps", I suppose you are referring to [Ubuntu Touch Core Apps project](http://launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone-coreapps/).

In that case (Ubuntu SDK/QML development) there are two tools that you could find useful for your purpose:

- [`PerformanceOverlay`](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.10/Ubuntu.PerformanceMetrics.PerformanceOverlay/) from `Ubuntu.PerformanceMetrics` module.

  According to documentation:

  > **PerformanceOverlay**
  >
  > > Overlay displaying performance related metrics (rendering time, CPU usage, etc.)
  > >
  > > PerformanceOverlay displays various performance related indicators to help developers detect issues in their application.
- Simply use [`top`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/top.1.html) or [`htop`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/htop.1.html) from terminal, to spot CPU usage for each thread used by your QML application.

The tools I listed above are especially good to check out issue related to QML Animation usage.

If you need to track the time required by a JS/QML function to be run, you can use `Console.time()` and `Console.timeEnd()` method.

See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-debugging.html for further information on `Console.time()`.